# How to make fragment honor soft input mode of activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity configured as follows in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

This activity creates a fragment. The fragment configures itself to be full-screen in onCreate(), e.g.:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
```

The fragment's layout is roughly this:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <!-- a fixed height header -->
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <!-- some EditTexts -->
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  <!-- a fixed height footer -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, when the fragment is displayed the soft keyboard is automatically shown and input mode is "adjustResize" instead of "adjustPan".  This causes the footer to always be visible; when the keyboard is shown the ScrollView just shrinks in height.

How can I configure the fragment to have the "stateHidden|adjustPan" behavior?  I'm getting the fragment functionality from the support library, if that matters.

Comment: why is that the soft keyboard is shown upon displaying the fragment?? can you post an image what it look like and a piece of code.

Comment: It was shown because the fragment contains EditTexts and the default soft input mode wasn't "stateHidden".  So it automatically gave focus to the first EditText and brought up the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Activity and on-screen soft keyboard both have got their own window.
`android:windowSoftInputMode` indicates how main window of activity should interact with window of on-screen soft keyboard.

I believe you are using `DialogFragment`. It has it's own window which floats on top of the activity's window. Hence the flags set for `Activity` through `android:windowSoftInputMode` are not applicable to `DialogFragment`.

One possible solution is set those flags for `DialogFragment`'s window programmatically. Use [getDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#getDialog()) to retrieve the underlying dialog instance, retrieve the window for the dialog using [getWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getWindow()) and specify the flags for soft input mode using [setSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int)).

```
public static class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Dialog layout inflater code
        // getDialog() need to be called only after onCreateDialog(), which is invoked between onCreate() and onCreateView(). 
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
       // return view code
   }
}
```

Comment: @user3249477 Yes, I've tried it on my device before posting the answer.

Comment: Weird. Somehow it doesn't for me. The keyboard just won't show. By the way the OP asked for state invisible not visible.

Comment: @user3249477 Hmm. Regarding visible flag you were right, I have updated the answer. Let's see whether it works for OP.

Comment: For posterity:  setting the soft input mode needs to happen in the fragment's onCreateView() method and not onCreate().

As follows:

  getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Answer (score -2):

You can close and open keyword manually in fragment. Detect the Window size run time and check the visiable view height is it match or not.

Because manifest do not know about fragment. Fragment is like as a collection of component view. We can use inside activity anywhere